# CLion fails to give suggestions, syntax highlighting, etc

Tags: c++, syntax-highlighting, clion, code-completion

Preface; I am working on a university game project which, other than meaning there are parts of my source that I can't share, should make no difference to my issue. Code shown below has been pruned of (apparent) useless information.

The issue is most prevalent in the `Play.cpp` file:

```cpp
#include "Play.h"
#include "../Engine.h"
#include "../TileManager.h"
#include "Scene.h"

Play::Play(Engine *engine) :
        Scene(engine),
        tm(TileManager()) {}
```

CLion does not show any syntax highlighting for `tm(TileManager())` line, nor does it give any code completions, nor any auto import.

`Play.h`:

```cpp
#pragma once

#include "../framework/header.h"
#include "Scene.h"
#include "../TileManager.h"

class Play : public Scene {
public:
    Play(Engine *engine);

private:
    TileManager tm;
};
```

And `Scene.h` (circular dependency to `Engine` since it manages scenes):

```cpp
#pragma once

class Engine;

struct Scene {
    explicit Scene(Engine *engine) : engine(engine) {}

protected:
    Engine *engine;
};
```

Any completion request on `tm.` in `Play.cpp` results in:

> No suggestions for members of TileManager

I would expect a list of the public methods in TileManager instead of this.

Does anyone have any insights as to why this may be happening? I am happy to provide further code as far as my restrictions allow.

CLion Version 2020.3

Comment: Try *Invalidate caches and restart*, remove CMake build directory and reload CMake projects.

Comment: I would have been so happy if that worked. At least it would have been simple :(
Sadly it did not change anything.

Comment: Do you have toolchains configured (https://www.jetbrains.com/help/clion/run-for-the-first-time.html#start-toolchains)? Can you please check?
Also, is it a CMake project? Can you reload it successfully (w/o errors) in CLion?

Comment: My toolchain was configured to use a newer cmake than was supported, it now works. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out that my Toolchain was configured to use a newer CMake version than CLion supports. Switching to the bundled version solved the issue.

[image: Toolchain configuration]

Comment: You can actually use CMake 3.20 with CLion 2021.1

Comment: Amazing, I hadn't updated yet, I will add the CLion version I was using to the question. You've been really helpful :)